# Debian live iwlwifi firmware error

Tags: linux, debian, boot, live-usb, error-handling

When booting Debian live onto my computer, I encountered the errors:

```
[    19.456064] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode (-2)
[    19.456183] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    19.456302] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[    19.457484] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode (-2)
[    19.457605] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    19.457705] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[    19.458278] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
```

I fould these errors when trying to set up a wireless connection by testing `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`.

If I do not have the proper firmware for my wireless card (Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265), I cannot download it because (obviously) I have not internet connection on Debian. Windows (Other OS) does not support `ext4` file systems (the persistence).

**Edit**

I am using Debian, Jessie, version 8.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright. The problem was that I didn't download the non-free version of Debian. The non-free version includes third party firmware.

See [the non-free package download page](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/).

Comment: Atleast explain what to look for in the link you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Download it and save on a storage that can be mounted... usb device, or other partition that you can mount from your debian live, then you can install the driver after bootup and can connect to internet.

edit:

Another way is to modify your live image or bake some new image of debian live that contain the corrected files.

Some distro give you a seperate folder contained in the image file to place files that should be replaced at boot up.

Comment: Yes I can replace the image (initrd.img), but I already have the most updated version (8.2.0). And furthermore, I wouldn't know where to download (or how to manually create) the image file.

Comment: May this can help you out... otherwise you need to completly recompile all. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/how-to-view-modify-and-recreate-initrd-img/

Comment: You don't need to modify `initrd.img`. Download the [firmware-iwlwifi](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-iwlwifi) package and transfer it to some filesystem accessible from your live system (a persistent diretory also suffices), then install the package after bootup.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are already documented by [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi).

Edit: If you experience problems with the wired network card, and the card is Realtek, the following could be useful:

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-realtek
```